# How to reverse apply a stash?

Tags: git, git-stash

I have a small patch saved away in my git stash.  I've applied it to my working copy using `git stash apply`.  Now, I'd like to back out those changes by reverse applying the patch (kind of like what `git revert` would do but against the stash).

Does anyone know how to do this?

**Clarification:** There are other changes in my working copy.  My particular case is hard to describe but you can imagine some debugging or experimental code that's in the stash.  Now it's mixed in my working copy with some other changes and I'd like to see the effect with and without the changes from the stash.

It doesn't look like stash supports this currently, but a `git stash apply --reverse` would be a nice feature.

Comment: Can't just just create a reversed patch by diffing between the current and previous revision? And then apply that one?

Comment: Are there changes in the working tree other than the applied stash?

Comment: Adding this here, ... was supposed to be a FAQ not a question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59973103/git-how-to-undo-revert-a-saved-stash-by-message-easily/59973105#59973105

Answer (score 245, accepted):

According to the [git-stash manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash), "A stash is represented as a commit whose tree records the state of the working directory, and its first parent is the commit at `HEAD` when the stash was created," and `git stash show -p` gives us "the changes recorded in the stash as a diff between the stashed state and its original parent.

To keep your other changes intact, use `git stash show -p | patch --reverse` as in the following:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/repo/.git/

$ echo Hello, world >messages

$ git add messages

$ git commit -am 'Initial commit'
[master (root-commit)]: created 1ff2478: "Initial commit"
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 messages

$ echo Hello again >>messages

$ git stash

$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

$ git stash apply
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   messages
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ echo Howdy all >>messages

$ git diff
diff --git a/messages b/messages
index a5c1966..eade523 100644
--- a/messages
+++ b/messages
@@ -1 +1,3 @@
 Hello, world
+Hello again
+Howdy all

$ git stash show -p | patch --reverse
patching file messages
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1 with fuzz 1.

$ git diff
diff --git a/messages b/messages
index a5c1966..364fc91 100644
--- a/messages
+++ b/messages
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 Hello, world
+Howdy all
```

**Edit:**

A light improvement to this is to use `git apply` in place of patch:

```
git stash show -p | git apply --reverse
```

Alternatively, you can also use `git apply -R` as a shorthand to `git apply --reverse`.

I've been finding this really handy lately...

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Seems like this might be a nice feature for stash.

Comment: Yes, `git apply -R` is an improvement, at least for me on my windows box with git bash as `patch --reverse` had problems to locate the file to patch (no real clue why the alternative worked). +1 and good explanation

Comment: wouldn't it be better to add `--index` just like this `git stash show -p | git apply --reverse --index`. Because you no longer need to add in the index the changes that are reverted back.

Comment: @Greg Bacon, hey, I've tried to go through the script that you outlined, but the patch failed when I ran `git stash show -p | git apply -R -v` with the message: `Checking patch messages... error: while searching for:
Hello, world Hello again error: patch failed: messages:1`. Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: I get **error: patch failed: /src/filename.java:46**  
**error: src/filename.java patch does not apply**

Comment: That's beautifully useful ; I'm working with the Terraform sources, which soil their own code by inserting autogenerated code alongside user code when you build them. With the autogenerated code in a stash, I can unpick that instantly like this.

Comment: The `…| git apply --reverse` works for me. The `…| patch --reverse` fails with `can't find file to patch at input line 5`. Archlinux system here, patch version 2.7.6.

Comment: Love the reverse one-liner.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 235):

```
git checkout -f
```

will remove any non-committed changes.

Comment: thanks, you help me from staged change which was not unapply.

Comment: This caused some odd problems for me.  My unit tests failed with obscure messages saying it couldn't read ARM.  I had to clean my build folder, derived data, and then restart my machine to get back to normal.

Comment: The OP did not ask for this though as this will remove all non-committed changes, not only changes introduced by the "stash apply". This can lead to loss of useful changes.

Comment: This is what I wanted, was able to run this, switch to my original branch and run stash apply to get my changes back.

Answer (score 95):

[`git stash`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)`[save]` takes your working directory state, and your index state, and stashes them away, setting index and working area to `HEAD` version.

`git stash apply` brings back those changes, so `git reset --hard` would remove them again.

`git stash pop` brings back those changes and removes top stashed change, so `git stash [save]` would return to previous (pre-pop) state in this case.

Answer (score 41):

The V1 git man page had a reference about un-applying a stash. The excerpt is below.

The newer V2 [git man page](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning) doesn't include any reference to un-applying a stash but the below still works well

**Un-applying a Stash**
In some use case scenarios you might want to apply stashed changes, do some work, but then un-apply those changes that originally came from the stash. Git does not provide such a stash un-apply command, but it is possible to achieve the effect by simply retrieving the patch associated with a stash and applying it in reverse:

```
$ git stash show -p stash@{0} | git apply -R
```

Again, if you don’t specify a stash, Git assumes the most recent stash:

```
$ git stash show -p | git apply -R
```

You may want to create an alias and effectively add a stash-unapply command to your Git. For example:

```
$ git config --global alias.stash-unapply '!git stash show -p | git apply -R'
$ git stash apply
$ #... work work work
$ git stash-unapply
```

Comment: For whatever reason this helpful section you linked "Un-applying a Stash" was removed from the 2nd version _-Latest version right now is 2.1.146, 2019-04-15-_ of this book [V2- Git Tools - Stashing and Cleaning](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning). Could be because the authors think there's a better way to do this that I can't seem to find.

Comment: @NadAlaba thanks for the heads up, have updated the answer to make note on the difference between v1 and v2... weird the git authors removed the section about un-applying a stash

Comment: This answer is especially useful for showing how to specify the applied stash. Thanks for including that important info! for those who might also have included untracked files, you can use `git stash show -p --all stash@{3} | git apply -R`

Answer (score 15):

This is long over due, but if i interpret the problem correctly i have found a simple solution, note, this is an explanation in my own terminology:

`git stash [save]` will save away current changes and set your current branch to the "clean state"

`git stash list` gives something like: `stash@{0}: On develop: saved testing-stuff`

`git apply stash@{0}` will set current branch as **before** `stash [save]`

`git checkout .` Will set current branch as **after** `stash [save]`

The code that is saved in the stash is not lost, it can be found by `git apply stash@{0}` again.

Anywhay, this worked for me!

Comment: Just to be sure, I applied a `git stash apply --reverse` first and then simply went back to `git stash apply stash@{x}` like you mention. Worked with no problems.

Answer (score 15):

> How to reverse apply a stash?

Apart from what others have mentioned, easiest way is first do

```
git reset HEAD
```

and then checkout all local changes

```
git checkout .
```

Comment: This is by far the easiest way as long as you have *absolutely no* local work you want to save. If you applied the wrong stash to a branch or hit merge conflicts that you don't want to resolve, this is the quick and easy way to undo it by completely reverting your working set to your branch's latest commit.

Answer (score 7):

you can apply two commands

`git reset .` // to reverse the files

then

`git checkout .`  // to reverse the changes

Comment: Please improve the quality of the answer by adding an explanations to each one of the commands. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can follow the image i shared to unstash if u accidentally tapped stashing.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Greg Bacon answer, in case binary files were added to the index and were part of the stash using

```
git stash show -p | git apply --reverse
```

may result in

```
error: cannot apply binary patch to '<YOUR_NEW_FILE>' without full index line
error: <YOUR_NEW_FILE>: patch does not apply
```

Adding `--binary` resolves the issue, but unfortunately haven't figured out why yet.

```
 git stash show -p --binary | git apply --reverse
```

Answer (score 2):

```
git stash show -p | git apply --reverse
```

Warning, that would not in every case: "[`git apply -R`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c23cd78e8127a2f80cc0357994209bc1bb81a4fe/Documentation/git-apply.txt#L104)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply#Documentation/git-apply.txt--R))</sup> did not handle patches that touch the same path twice correctly, which has been corrected with Git 2.30 (Q1 2021).

This is most relevant in a patch that changes a path from a regular file to a symbolic link (and vice versa).

See [commit b0f266d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0f266de11e9dc3a140ff9407a47604bef0e257f) (20 Oct 2020) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c23cd78](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c23cd78e8127a2f80cc0357994209bc1bb81a4fe), 02 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`apply`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0f266de11e9dc3a140ff9407a47604bef0e257f): when `-R`, also reverse list of sections
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Tan</sup>

> A patch changing a symlink into a file is written with 2 sections (in the code, represented as "struct patch"): firstly, the deletion of the symlink, and secondly, the creation of the file.
>
> When applying that patch with `-R`, the sections are reversed, so we get: (1) creation of a symlink, then (2) deletion of a file.
>
> This causes an issue when the "deletion of a file" section is checked, because Git observes that the so-called file is not a file but a symlink, resulting in a "wrong type" error message.
>
> What we want is: (1) deletion of a file, then (2) creation of a symlink.
>
> In the code, this is reflected in the behavior of `previous_patch()` when invoked from `check_preimage()` when the deletion is checked.
> Creation then deletion means that when the deletion is checked, `previous_patch()` returns the creation section, triggering a mode conflict resulting in the "wrong type" error message.
>
> But deletion then creation means that when the deletion is checked, `previous_patch()` returns `NULL`, so the deletion mode is checked against lstat, which is what we want.
>
> There are also other ways a patch can contain 2 sections referencing the same file, for example, in [7a07841c0b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7a07841c0ba8d791dd4c7363eaf004b4a7d11fb6) ("`git-apply`: handle a patch that touches the same path more than once better", 2008-06-27, Git v1.6.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7ebd52aa0e58df6bac5f0f87a591da17eb3324a6)). "[`git apply -R`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b0f266de11e9dc3a140ff9407a47604bef0e257f/Documentation/git-apply.txt#L104)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply#Documentation/git-apply.txt--R))</sup> fails in the same way, and this commit makes this case succeed.
>
> Therefore, when building the list of sections, build them in reverse order (by adding to the front of the list instead of the back) when `-R` is passed.

Answer (score 0):

This is in addition to the above answers but adds search for the git stash based on the message as the stash number can change when new stashes are saved.
I have written a couple of bash functions:

```
apply(){
  if [ "$1" ]; then
    git stash apply `git stash list | grep -oPm1 "(.*)(?=:.*:.*$1.*)"`
  fi
}
remove(){
  if [ "$1" ]; then
    git stash show -p `git stash list | grep -oPm1 "(.*)(?=:.*:.*$1.*)"` | git apply -R
    git status
  fi
}
```

1. Create stash with name (message) `$ git stash save "my stash"`
2. To appply named `$ apply "my stash"`
3. To remove named stash `$ remove "my stash"`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue myself, I think all you need to do is `git reset --hard` and you will not lose your changes or any untracked changes.

If you read the docs in `git stash --help` it states that apply is "Like pop, but do not remove the state from the stash list" so the state still resides there, you can get it back.

Alternatively, if you have no conflicts, you can just `git stash` again after testing your changes.

If you do have conflicts, don't worry, `git reset --hard` won't lose them, as
"Applying the state can fail with conflicts; in this case, it is not removed from the stash list. You need to resolve the conflicts by hand and call git stash drop manually afterwards."

Answer (score 0):

For me, i had just typed the wrong name of the repository when checking out. So there literally was not remote to pull.

So, in addition to checking the casing, check the branch name *spelling*, or better yet, copy and paste it -to rule it out.

Answer (score 0):

If there are any merge conflicts, using `git stash show -p | git apply --reverse` will not work. If you are using IntelliJ or Android studio, try using `Local History` under `File` menu. This help me with the revert