# git: how do I merge between branches while keeping some changesets exclusive to one branch?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, dvcs, merge

There's a special place in hell for people who hardcode absolute paths and database credentials into multiple random places in web applications. Sadly, before they go to hell they're wreaking havoc on Earth. And we  have to deal with their code.

I have to perform a few small changes to one of such web applications. I create a new branch `features`, and perform a global find & replace to update the paths and credentials to my local environment. I commit that. I also tag this as `local`.

I merrily leap into perilous hacking penitence, and after a perplexing hundred patches, I want to merge my `features` changes into the `master` branch, but I do not want the one `local` commit to be merged.

Onwards, I'll be merging back and forth between `master` and `features`, and I'd like `local` to stay put in `features`, and never ever show up in `master`.

Ideally, I'd like all this to happen magically, with as little funny parameters and whatnot as possible.

Is there a simple obvious way to do it that I'm missing?

I can think of a couple, but they all require me to **remember** that I don't want that commit. And that's definitely not my forte. Especially with such poorly hacked programs.

Failing that, I'm interested in more convoluted, manual-ish ways to handle the situation.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes. Ideally I should refactor the stupid application. As soon as I get paid to do it. (And I can think of a few other cases where such pattern would make sense, even in well structured apps)

Comment: Added a response to your comment in my answer.

Comment: The other option: use one of the quilt extensions (guilt, stacked git, etc) and make your rename a patch in a queue.  I believe these extensions won't let you merge a patch that hasn't been integrated back into the regular commits, so you can't accidentally merge it in.  Still not ideal because you need to remember to pop and then re-apply the patch every time you have new normal commits, but you solve the problem of forgetting you don't want that commit.

Answer (score 6):

My solution to this problem uses rebase rather than merge

Starting with a commit tree like this:

```
a-b-c <-- master
 \
  d <-- local
   \
    e-f-g <-- dev
```

$ git rebase --onto master local dev

```
       master 
       V 
   a-b-c-e'-f'-g' <-- dev
     \
      d <-- local
```

$ git checkout master

$ git merge dev

```
               master 
               V 
   a-b-c-e'-f'-g' <-- dev
     \
      d <-- local
```

$ git rebase --onto master master local

```
               master 
               V 
   a-b-c-e'-f'-g' <-- dev
                \
                 d' <-- local
```

$ git branch -f dev local

```
               master 
               V 
   a-b-c-e'-f'-g'
                \
                 d' <-- local
                 ^
                 dev
```

Comment: OK. Now, how about a good link to a place that explains all this magic ? :) I have scanned git-scm.com/book earlier, but I have no basis for understanding what you just did.

Answer (score 3):

You can use git cherry pick to only merge the patches you select. Just cherry pick every commit except for the local one over to the master branch.

Comment: I like this answer, except: how do you do this if you have a *lot* of changes?  Is there a one-line pattern to just exclude one patch from a set?

Comment: By analogy, the Mercurial transplant extension has a flag for this: `hg transplant -p local`.  (There are a lot of other arguments you'd need to make it work, but this is what would skip the given changeset.)

Comment: @quark: Interactive rebase can do just that. `git checkout -b tmp features && git rebase -i --onto dev dev tmp` would place you in an editor where you can choose which commits between `dev` and `features` to place on a new branch `tmp` starting from `dev`. You can squash multiple commits into one as well, and even re-order commits if you're feeling adventurous.

Answer (score 1):

A technical (Git) solution would be using [**`git attributes`**](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes), using the attribute merge.

```
merge
```

> The attribute `merge` affects how three versions of a file is merged when a file-level merge is necessary during `git merge`.

You will find in the SO question "[How do I tell git to always select my local version for conflicted merges on a specific file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928646/how-do-i-tell-git-to-always-select-my-local-version-for-conflicted-merges-on-a-sp/930495#930495)" an example of using such an attribute, to force keeping the local version of certain files when merging to a given branch.

> The problem with setting merge attributes is that the files that contain the paths may contain other changed code, which I want merged

Do not forget you can associate any kind of script to manage those merges through `git attributes`. That include a script able to keep changes you want local, while merging the rest. It is more complicated to write such a "merge manager", but it is a way toward an ad-hoc automated solution.

---

A less-technical solution would be to separate the **configuration values** from the **configuration files**:

- the configuration file contains only names to be replaced
- the configuration values are several files (one per environment) with the actual values for each name.

A script is used to replace the name in the actual config file by the values of one of the config values files needed for a given environment.

Comment: The problem with setting merge attributes is that the files that contain the paths may contain other changed code, which I want merged. So it's more about that one changeset rather than the entire file.

Comment: Interesting response, but yea, seems like a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

ok. this is not guaranteed to work every time but something like this can work (and in the cases it wont you will have a conflicting changes anyway that has to be resolved):

- do your local branch
- do local-only change
- continue development

when doing merge to the master:

- `rebase -i master` from your branch and move the local-only change to the **END** of the patch chain.
- resolve any conflicts in the process. If the local-only change is in the config files and you are not touching them in the regular development, then you will have no problems. If, otherwise, you do have a conflict, then this is a case when you actually change in the same area and it needs your attention to resolve anyway.
- check out master
- merge your local-branch -1:

  git merge local^

This will leave you with master having all the changes on the local except for the last one.

If you have multiple local=only changes, I suggest you **squash** them together during rebase.

Answer (score 0):

I would do an interactive rebase against master and move your path-name-fixup-commit to the end.  Then, you can merge up to the that point.  Just keep moving your special commit to the end.

You may also find the stash useful.  Instead of actually committing the path name fixups you could stash them away.  If try this approach you may want to check out the question on [How to reverse apply a stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020132).

Comment: Yea, but that doesn't help me merge back and forth. I tried using the stash for a while but it gets boring really fast. It's better to rebase -i the commit out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, because no answer so far provided a straightforward solution, I'll assume what I want to do is impossible, and add to the pile of occasionally useful solutions:

If you're always developing on the `features` branch, then you can merge `features` to `master`, and then, in `master`, `git revert local`. (Where `local` is the tag referencing the commit where you customized the paths, etc for your local environment.)

Now you must never merge `master` into `features`, because that would merge the reverse `local` commit too.

In this case `master` becomes sort of a deployment branch, only ever receiving merges from other branches. (Ideally, only from the `features` branch.)

This goes downhill very easily, just add another developer to the workflow and things get really messy. Still can be worked around by using explicit merge strategies, but it's generally a pain.

Comment: Sounds like the real answer is to fix the code.  Extract the hard coded paths into a config file which can be overridden with a local config file.  Track a default config file but not the local config file or something along those lines.

Comment: Yes that's generally good advice, but see my own comment under my question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would work, but:

1. Create a commit that, given the "master" version of the config files, turns them into the version you need locally.  Note the SHA-1.  We'll call it `MAKE_LOCAL`
2. Create a commit that, given your local version of the config files, turns them into the version appropriate for master. Note the SHA-1.  We'll call it `MAKE_REMOTE`
3. Using git hooks, when you commit:

   1. `git cherry-pick MAKE_REMOTE` (or use `git diff` and `patch`)
   2. Allow the commit to commence
   3. `git cherry-pick MAKE_LOCAL` (or use `git diff` and `patch`)

I think there is an even better way of transforming files in this manner, but I can't recall (if you can find shacon's git presentation from RubyConf, and can wade through 800 slides, it's in there with some great examples).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, if I had to do something like this and was for whatever reason prevented from refactoring credentials as I go, I'd add two more branches, ending up with an arrangement similar to the following:

`master`: the original code you inherited

`localcred`: branch from master, and add just the one patch that changes all the credentials to what you need locally.  Treat this branch as read-only hereafter (and possibly add a hook to prevent accidental commits).

`feature`: branch from master, and all fixes go here (and possibly add a hook to prevent merging with the patch in localcred)

`local`: a branch (not a tag!) that will start out as a branch of `localcred`, and then merge feature whenever you need to run your unit tests.  All testing happens from here, but no development happens here.  In addition, this branch is disposable, because you might want to rebase inside of `feature`, and the fastest way to deal with the result will be to delete branch `local`, branch it again from `localcred` and merge `feature` before running your tests.  This is likely to be a common enough operation in my workflow that I'd build an alias to do it repeatedly in just a few keystrokes, but I work the hell out of the disposability of Git branches, which kind of freaks out some people who watch me, so YMMV.

When you think your fixes are ready for publication, you do your final rebase of `feature` to clean up the history, dump and recreate `local` for your final test, merge `feature` into `master`, and once that's accepted upstream, merge `master` into `localcred` and rebase your credential patch to the top, then dump and recreate `local` and `feature` and play the game all over again.

If you want to rapidly test a large set of tiny variations of code without having to commit and merge each time, checkout `local`, make your changes until you're happy, commit, and immediately cherry-pick from `local` into `feature`, then drop and recreate local.

Does that satisfy your needs?

Answer (score 0):

The question is an old one, but I still have not found a good answer. Currently I am facing the same issue and below is my workaround to deal with it:

There are two branches in my local repo: `master` and `local_settings`.
Having cut off the `local_settings` branch from `master` I committed there all local paths, not tagging and not trying to remember them.
During local development I am switched to the `local_settings` branch, so I can run an application using local paths. But when it is time to commit I stash a current state and switch to the `master` branch. Then I pop the stashed changeset and commit it into `master`. And the final step is to switch back to `local_settings`, merge from `master` and continue development. 
To recap: I commit into the `local_settings` branch only changes that will stay locally and will never go into master; and no merges from `local_settings` to `master`.

Now let's say I need to add a "good" modification to a file with a local path added earlier, but the "good" modification is wanted in the `master` branch.
I do my changes when the working copy is a head for `local_settings`, stash it and check out `master`. The stash keeps a changeset, that is relative to `local_settings`, although I am on `master` already. `git stash pop` applies the stashed changeset to the working copy and ends up having a diff relative to master, but only with the recent modification excluding the local path that had been added earlier and was not a part of the recent stashed changeset. Hence it can be committed without messing paths in the `master` branch. Afterwards again merge from `master` to `local_settings`.