# GIT stash apply reverse doesn't work with js and rb files

Tags: git, newline, reverse, git-stash, git-patch

I'm trying to figure out why GIT does not apply reverse patch on javascript and ruby files, but does it on php files. My steps are:

`...modifying some php, ruby and js files...`

`git stash` #saving changes into stash

`git stash apply` #applying them

`git stash show -p | git apply -R` #reverse patching

it works fine and does un-apply my stashed changes, but only for php files, not for ruby or javascript. All files (even php) has `CRLF` line endings. When I tried files with `LF` line endings, no issues were at all, but I'm still wondering, why it does work only for particular file types in case of `CRLF` lines.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I can't replicate. What version of git are you using?

Comment: Linking for additional help from other folks researching this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1020132/320399

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the issue and I think my solution would be usefull for others. Actually, it was happening after initinal migration from Subversion to Git. The issue was that files in project had different line endings, so it is not depends on filetype. When Git was trying to convert them all to one format during checkout, it was not correct and in some cases `CRLF` was broken. Solution I found:

`git config --global core.autocrlf input`# Set this setting on OSX or Linux

`git config --global core.autocrlf true`# Set this setting on Windows

`git rm --cached -r .`

`git add .`

`git commit -m "Line endings fix. Now all lines are in LF format"`

`git reset --hard`

After that I have a clean branch with all files in one format. Hope, this will help someone.