# How to go back to latest commit after seeing old stash

Tags: git, git-stash

I applied a stash and then made several commits. After that, I decided to do a quick look at the stash again. So I typed:

```
git stash apply stash@{0}
```

I just wanted to see and did nothing. Now I just want to go back to my latest commit. When I do

```
git checkout master
```

It gives error message

```
error: you need to resolve your current index first
test.js: needs merge
```

So in this condition, how to go back to my latest commit?
I also want to know how to check old stash the right way.

Comment: i think this might be it:
[How to reverse apply a stash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020132/how-to-reverse-apply-a-stash) Dit yout tried it already?

Comment: You can try Soft resetting your head to previous commit

Comment: this is generic thing whenever you checkout your current state must be clean meaning you need to commit/stash your changes, resolve your conflicts. Try resolving conflict then try checkout it should work

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to reverse apply the stash : Retrieve the stash patch and apply in reverse

`git stash show -p stash@{0} | git apply -R`

Or try

`git reset --merge` and see if you can revert from the new state.

Comment: Looks like test.js file has some change in your local other than what's there in the stash

Comment: Just try to stash whatever is there and then you can checkout master branch. Once no error, delete the stash you just saved. A hacky way if you don't care about what extra changes are there in test.js