# GIT: unapply a stash - too many revisions specified

Tags: git, git-stash

I'm sorry if the solution is trivial, but I'm not a GIT expert and I didn't find anything on the internet.

I stashed some changes, and I'm having hard times at reverting them. Maybe I sent the `git stash` command twice, I hope this didn't make me lose everything.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020132/how-to-reverse-apply-a-stash) and [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing), I've tried the following commands:

```
git stash pop
```

And I received:

> ```
> src/schema/schema-generator2.js: needs merge
> unable to refresh index
> ```

So I tried:

```
git merge
```

> ```
> error: Merging is not possible because you have unmerged files
> ```

Then I tried:

```
git stash apply stash@{0}
```

> ```
> unknown option: -encodedCommand
> ```

```
git stash apply
```

> ```
> src/schema/schema-generator2.js: needs merge
> ```

```
git stash apply --index
```

> ```
> src/schema/schema-generator2.js: needs merge
> ```

```
git stash show -p stash@{0} | git apply -R
```

> ```
> git : Too many revisions specified: 'stash@' 'MAA=' 'xml' 'xml'
> In riga:1 car:1
> + git stash show -p stash@{0} | git apply -R
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Too many revisi...A=' 'xml' 'xml':String) [], RemoteException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
> error: unrecognized input
> ```

In the above text I wrote as code the message, and as quote the answer. I hope it's clear.

I don't understand what's happening, why nothing works? What can I do to un-stash my changes?

Comment: can you post the output of `git status` command

Comment: You forgot to mention that you using PowerShell as shell. And `{` is special character for PowerShell in this example.

Comment: @PetSerAl you are right, I'm using VS Code and many errors stop appearing when I use terminal.

Comment: By the way, I solved the problem, even if I can't explain how. Probably it was just a problem with VS Code and restarting it was enough

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is the stashed changes and latest HEAD of your branch are not automatically mergable, specifically in `src/schema/schema-generator2.js` file

This means you will have to manually resolve the merge conflicts

The best way to do this would be to convert the stashed changed into a patch file and try applying the patch file. You will still see the merge conflicts but will have better control of resolving the changes

```
$ git stash show -p --color=never > my-stashed-changes.patch
# This should show the same merge error
$ git apply my-stashed-changes.patch
# modify the patch file to resolve conflicts and apply again
```